# Makefile:3: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, ssh, makefile, openssl

I have attempted what I could, with the answers found on StackOverflow on this question. I do not believe the issue is with tabs. Here is the makefile:

---

```
#   $OpenBSD: Makefile,v 1.15 2010/02/09 08:55:31 markus Exp $

.include <bsd.own.mk>

SUBDIR= lib ssh sshd ssh-add ssh-keygen ssh-agent scp sftp-server \
    ssh-keysign ssh-keyscan sftp ssh-pkcs11-helper

distribution:
    ${INSTALL} -C -o root -g wheel -m 0644 ${.CURDIR}/ssh_config \
        ${DESTDIR}/etc/ssh/ssh_config
    ${INSTALL} -C -o root -g wheel -m 0644 ${.CURDIR}/sshd_config \
        ${DESTDIR}/etc/ssh/sshd_config

.include <bsd.subdir.mk>
```

---

I have attempted to put a tab before line 3 (where the issue is), and had the following error appear:

```
Makefile:3: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

This isn't a makefile of my own design--it was downloaded directly from here:
http://www.openssh.com/openbsd.html
(first download link)

Additionally, based on another answer to this question, I have used the following command:

```
root@server:/usr/src/ssh# cat -e -t -v Makefile
```

which output the following:

```
 \#^I$OpenBSD: Makefile,v 1.15 2010/02/09 08:55:31 markus Exp $$ $ .include <bsd.own.mk>$ $ SUBDIR=^Ilib ssh sshd ssh-add ssh-keygen
 ssh-agent scp sftp-server \$ ^Issh-keysign ssh-keyscan sftp
 ssh-pkcs11-helper$ $ distribution:$ ^I${INSTALL} -C -o root -g wheel
 -m 0644 ${.CURDIR}/ssh_config \$ ^I    ${DESTDIR}/etc/ssh/ssh_config$ ^I${INSTALL} -C -o root -g wheel -m 0644 ${.CURDIR}/sshd_config \$ ^I 
 ${DESTDIR}/etc/ssh/sshd_config$ $ .include <bsd.subdir.mk>$
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you re-post the results of `cat` at the end and use code formatting (indent each line with 4 spaces) rather than blockquotes (`>` in front of each line)? The blockquote version is all mangled.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I went ahead and deleted the '>'. If your issue was with there only being 5 lines when it appears there should be more, the output was actually exactly like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This makefile is written for BSD `make`.  You're trying to run it with GNU `make`.  They use different formats.

In particular, the `.include` command is not valid in GNU `make`.

Comment: Thank you. This looks to be correct. user2931171 did provide a solution to the problem, rather than just an explanation though. I don't know the proper etiquette for selecting answers here--you did answer my question, but he provided information that more appropriately addressed my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged your question with "linux", I assume you're using Linux and not OpenBSD. The ssh version you want for Linux is the portable one, but it seems you downloaded the OpenBSD-specific one. Try http://www.openssh.com/portable.html . See the openssh front page for details on the OpenBSD/portable split releases.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to the Linux-compatible version. You are correct in that I downloaded the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/vimrc` or `/etc/virc`, Comment out the `set expandtab`

```
"set expandtab       " Always uses spaces instead of tab characters (et)
```

Using `tab` reedit the Makefile file. You can look also see the keywords `missing separator` by `info make`, you will see:

```
`missing separator.  Stop.'
`missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.'
     This means that `make' could not understand much of anything about
     the makefile line it just read.  GNU `make' looks for various
     separators (`:', `=', recipe prefix characters, etc.) to indicate
     what kind of line it's parsing.  This message means it couldn't
     find a valid one.

     One of the most common reasons for this message is that you (or
     perhaps your oh-so-helpful editor, as is the case with many
     MS-Windows editors) have attempted to indent your recipe lines
     with spaces instead of a tab character.  In this case, `make' will
     use the second form of the error above.  Remember that every line
     in the recipe must begin with a tab character (unless you set
     `.RECIPEPREFIX'; *note Special Variables::).  Eight spaces do not
     count.  *Note Rule Syntax::.
```